# How do you play barre chords which are at an angle?

Tags: guitar, technique, chords

*I read about the concept of an angled/oblique barre chord, where you use your index finger to play 2 different frets across different strings like so:*

```
-4- 3rd
-2- 1st
-3- 1st
-4- 2nd
---
-4- 4th
```

*(I am aware that this might be a nonsense chord, but I hope it gets the concept across)*

The concept again appeared on the question [Fingerstyle guitar - how to play this arpeggio?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/fingerstyle-guitar-how-to-play-this-arpeggio?noredirect=1#comment20981_15895)
I looked around the net and found [this forum post](http://www.thegearpage.net/board/archive/index.php/t-1195822.html), but nothing on SE.

So, Does anyone have any practical experience/guides on how to use such a technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's very hard to do on neighboring strings. I do use it occasionally between the low E and the high E (that's the easiest combination for me) when playing a major 7 chord in drop-3 voicing, with an additional major 7 on the high E string:

(from low E to high E):

> 5 X 6 6 5 4

where I use fingers

> 1 3 4 5 1

so there's an angled barre chord from the low E 5th fret to the high E 4th fret.

The chord you gave as an example - which by the way is perfectly fine, it's an Ab9sus4 - I would play with the following fingering

> T 3 2 1 4

(where T is my thumb).

Comment: Did you know that it was an Ab9sus4 off the top of your head?

Comment: Yes, I'm into jazz harmony.